# Find the limit points of $\:{x_n}$, where $\:x_n=1+(-1)^n+n\sin({n^{-1}})$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

Find the limit points of $\:{x_n}$, where $\:x_n=1+(-1)^n+n\sin({n^{-1}})$

My Work:

For $\:n=2k-1$, $\:x_n=n\sin({n^{-1}})$

For $\:n=2k$,$\:\:x_n=2\left(1+\large\frac {n}{2}\:\normalsize \sin({n^{-1})}\right)$

Is this sufficient analysis? To say that when $\:n\:$ is odd, it is equal to that product, but when it's even, it is equivalent to the above statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost finished! We need to observe that since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin(n^{-1})}{n^{-1}}=1$.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the missing $1$.